# Using the Facebook iOS SDK in a CI build - Framework not found

Tags: ios, react-native, azure-devops, cocoapods, react-native-fbsdk

My React Native app makes use of the `react-native-fbsdk` package, and I am trying to make the iOS build work on a CI server (Azure DevOps). The main problem is that the Facebook SDK is expected to be installed in `~/Documents/FacebookSDK`, which doesn't work on a CI build server.

I've hit quite a few issues. The error I am getting at the moment is:

```
▸ Linking TzoApp
⚠️  ld: directory not found for option '-L/Users/vsts/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TzoApp-bghowrtdysrbywbsslmkxejgzgoc/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/React'
⚠️  ld: directory not found for option '-F/Users/vsts/agent/2.149.2/work/1/s/tzoapp-mobile/ios/Pods/FirebaseCore/Frameworks'
⚠️  ld: directory not found for option '-F/Users/vsts/agent/2.149.2/work/1/s/tzoapp-mobile/ios/Pods/FirebaseMessaging/Frameworks'
⚠️  ld: directory not found for option '-F/Users/vsts/Documents/FacebookSDK'

❌  ld: framework not found FBSDKCoreKit

❌  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I am installing the Facebook SDK via Cocoapods, and have the following in my podfile:

```
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 4.40.0'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 4.40.0'
pod 'FBSDKShareKit', '~> 4.40.0'
```

My Framework Search Paths are as follow:

```
FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS = (
    "$(inherited)",
    "\"${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks\"",
    "\"${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCore/Frameworks\"",
    "\"${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseInstanceID/Frameworks\"",
    "\"${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseMessaging/Frameworks\"",
    "\"$(HOME)/Documents/FacebookSDK\"",
);
```

and my Header Search Paths are:

```
HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = (
    "$(inherited)",
    "$(SRCROOT)/../node_modules/react-native-firebase/ios/RNFirebase/**",
    "$(SRCROOT)/../node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/ios/RCTFBSDK/**",
    "$(SRCROOT)/Pods/Headers/**",
    "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/Facebook-iOS-SDK",
    "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/Facebook-iOS-SDK/FacebookSDK",
    "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/FBSDKCoreKit",
    "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit",
);
```

Can someone help getting the build to work?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is would help, But at least let's try. Look try to copy each of the Framework files from Facebook SDK (FBSDKCoreKit, FBSDKLoginKit, FBSDKShareKit) folder into RCTFBSDK framework folder in the Xcode libraries section like the picture below

[image]

Note: Don't forget to check (copy files if needed) when you drop your files inside the framework folder.
Also, clean your project and re-run it again.

Hopefully this will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have always found Cocoapods a bit hit and miss. If you read the Cocoapods documentation they recommend not including your Pods directory in your .gitignore. We currently include our Pods in source control. This is partly because some are hosted internally on an internal network not accessible to Azure DevOps. It also has the benefit of developers being able to clone and build straight away.